# MYSQL: Count the number of times a specific integer appears in a column then making a count of how many of these are present?

Tags: mysql, select, count, group-by

I have a table with figures like this

```
Report used                  UserID

 1                             2

 1                             2

 1                             2

 2                             2
```

In this case I'm looking to count the 1's in the 'Report used' column, which would give me the value 3. I might find a few of these in this column for different users, so I'd want to count how many times I found 3 1's.

I've tried using SELECT COUNT to count specific numbers but I'm not sure how to count this count, if you follow me.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Can you show exactly what the expected result should look like?

Comment: So here the result would be 3 because the figure '1' is present three times in the report used column.

Imagine there are several instances where there are 3 "1's" in the report used column for different users. I want to make a count of these instances.

Comment: It's still not very clear to me... for the specific example data you have posted the expected result is 1, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT userid, COUNT(reportused) onescount 
FROM tablename 
WHERE reportused = 1
GROUP BY userid
```

Also check this:

```
SELECT COUNT(userid) 
FROM (SELECT userid, COUNT(reportused) onescount 
      FROM tablename 
      WHERE reportused = 1
      GROUP BY userid) a 
WHERE onescount = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've got it right:

```
select Report_used,RU_count,count(*) 
from
(select Report_used, UserID, count(*) RU_Count 
    from t 
    group by Report_used, UserID) t1
group by Report_used,RU_count;
```